# ngRoute breaks two way data binding

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, ngroute, angular-google-maps

I have ngRoute working perfectly in my app. However the home page which uses http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/ works fine on page load however navigating to a different page and going back to it breaks all the data binding. Whilst `console.log()` proves values are changing in the controller the view fails to update to reflect the new values as if the digest cycle is no longer firing. I tried explicitly calling `$scope.appy()` and `$scope.diget()` but neither worked. There are no js errors visible in the console.

Comment: We need code examples to comment on that problem.

Comment: please reproduce issue with plunkr / fiddle so that we can help you..

Comment: turns out it is only happening on the page that uses http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/